# bash cat all files that contains a certain string in file name

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, cat

In `bash`, how would you `cat` all files in a directory that contains a certain string in its filename. For example I have files named:

```
test001.csv
test002.csv
test003.csv
result001.csv
result002.csv
```

I want to `cat` all `.csv` that contains the string `test` in the file name together, and all `.csv` that contains the string `result` in the file name together.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just:

```
cat *test*.csv
cat *result*.csv
```

For all files with `test` (or in case of the second one `result`) in their name.

Answer (score 4):

The shell itself can easily find all files matching a simple wildcard.

```
cat *test*.csv >testresult
```

You want to take care so that the output file's name does not match the wildcard. (It's technically harmless, but good practice.)

The shell will expand the wildcard in alphabetical order. Most shells will obey your locale, so the definition of "alphabetical order" may depend on current locale settings.

Answer (score -3):

Here's very simple way

```
cat `find . -name "*test*.csv"`
```

Comment: Cool, works like a dream. I basically used cat `find . -name "*test*.csv"` > test.csv

Comment: This is wrong if there are subdirectories with matching files, and huge overkill if there are not.

Comment: But this is right if we should look in all subdirectories :)
That's why here allowed more than one opinion

Comment: The question quite clearly  asks  for matches in one directory.

Comment: It's also wrong if any of the matched files contain whitespace or special pattern match characters.